# I'm trying to disable the buy buttons on my WordPress site for products that are virtual

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, themes, product

as the title states, I'm trying to remove the buy button for virtual products. I am using the Astra theme in WordPress alongside Woocommerce, and Elementor.

Now my issue is that with my current implementation, it does remove the button from the individual product page. However it still displays the button on the categories page, which is a pain. I have tried setting the price to nothing, and while that does work. It doesn't help as I still want the products to have their prices listed.

I have added the following code to the functions.php section of my duplicated theme file;

```
function buy_filter()
{
    if ( ! is_product() ) return;
    
    $product = get_product();
    
    if ($product->is_virtual('yes'))
    {
        //$product->is_purchasable('false')
        
        //remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
        //remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30); 
        
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 30);
    }
}

add_action ('wp', 'buy_filter');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I'm happy to give any more details I can to aid in the matter.

Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the specific product by it's ID, I have modified a few part of your code and removed few of the hooks you used. Please  add those if required.

```
function woocommerce_remove_cart()
{
    if ( ! is_product() ) return;
    $product_id=get_the_ID();
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    if ($product->is_virtual('yes'))
    {

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }

}//end of function
add_action('wp_head','woocommerce_remove_cart');
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I pasted the code in, but all of the products just reverted to having the buttons back, I will try to put all of those actions back in, just to see, and I will let you know

Comment: So if I add the same hooks in, I get the same results as what I started with, where the buy button does get removed from the individual product page, but it's still there on the category page

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'woocommerce_isproduct_purchasable', 10, 2 );

function woocommerce_isproduct_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ) {
    return ($product->is_virtual( 'yes' ) ) ? false : $purchasable;
}
```

This is the hook you are looking for

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping!

I pasted the code in, but it throws the following error

Comment: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function woocommerce_isproduct_purchasable(), 1 passed in wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 289 and exactly 2 expected in wp-content/themes/astra-child/functions.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(289): woocommerce_isproduct_purchasable(true)
#1 wp-includes/plugin.php(212): WP_Hook->apply_filters(true, Array)
#2 wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php(1543): apply_filters('woocommerce_is_...', true, Object(WC_Product_Variation))

Comment: #3 wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variation.php(550): WC_Product->is_purchasable()
#4 wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-sess